# Close the keyboard on UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, ios-4.2, iphone

I'm a newbie developing for iOS devices. I inserted an UITextField on InterfaceBuilder, and I assigned with the code:

```
@interface ComposeViewController : UIViewController {
 id <ComposeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
 IBOutlet UITextField *notificationTitle;
}
```

How I could allow to close the keyboard when the user press the "Return" key?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Set the Delegate of the UITextField to your ViewController, add a referencing outlet between the File's Owner and the UITextField, then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == yourTextField) {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: If this is not yourTextField, shouldn't we return YES?  For other fields we should get default behavior, since the questioner doesn't specify any special action.

Answer (score 23):

Inherit UITextFieldDelegate protocol
In viewDidLoad method set:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Implement the delegate method below:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ 
   [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: Remember that `yourTextField.delegate = self` generates a warning in XCode if you don't set to comply with `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in your class's header file.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and implement `textFieldShouldReturn:`, that's you will catch "return" event.

Inside `textFieldShouldReturn` write `[notificationTitle resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 0):

Add a action target to the event Did End on Exit(UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit), in the target function remove the first responder from the text filed using resignFirstResponder.
Adding action target

Note:
1. Nib --- give action to even Did End on Exit
2. In code add target action to the event UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit.