# how to add an action on UITextField return key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I have a button and text textfield in my view. when i click on the textfield a keyboard appears and i can write on the textfield and i also able to dismiss the keyboard by clicking on the button by adding:

```
[self.inputText resignFirstResponder];
```

Now I want to enable return key of keyboard. when i will press on the keyboard keyboard will disappear and something will happen. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761648/close-the-keyboard-on-uitextfield

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Ensure "self" subscribes to `UITextFieldDelegate` and initialise inputText with:

```
self.inputText.delegate = self;
```

Add the following method to "self":

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.inputText) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Or in Swift:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == inputText {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**With extension style in swift 3.0**

First, set up delegate for your text field.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.inputText.delegate = self
}
```

Then conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` in your view controller's extension

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == inputText {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

While the other answers work correctly, I prefer doing the following:

In viewDidLoad(), add

`self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onReturn), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEndOnExit)`

and define the function

```
@IBAction func onReturn() {
    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    // do whatever you want...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a target on textField setup function on viewDidLoad, then add its related function as selector.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldShouldReturn(sender:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
}

@objc func textFieldShouldReturn(sender: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: This code doesn´t compile. The couples of parentheses is not complete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use Target-Action UIKit mechanism for "primaryActionTriggered" UIEvent sent from UITextField when a keyboard done button is tapped.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: Selector("actionMethodName"), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
```