# resign first responder UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, resignfirstresponder

I am so sorry to post this, since it has been asked a million of times, but whenever i try to use one of the solutions, it is either outdated, or won't work with my code. (or maybe i am just doing it wrong)

i have 5 textfields and a textview, that go into an email, and i am trying to minimise the keyboard when im done, but i dont know how to.

I also tried to make it go to the next text field, until the last one, but that doesn't need to be done.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        text6.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.text1 {
        self.text2.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == self.text2 {
        self.text3.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == self.text3 {
        self.text4.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == self.text4 {
        self.text5.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.text5.resignFirstResponder();
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: would it not be better to check that each field has some non-zero length content and resign when they do ? you can also put a done button on the top of the keyboard...

Comment: your set delegate method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553396/how-to-add-an-action-on-uitextfield-return-key

Answer (score 13, accepted):

first you have to add `UITextFieldDelegate` in .h

then in .m

```
yourtextfield.delegate = self
```

then apply this code

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@Peter Boesen:

To minimise the keyboard when done. i.e. when "return" key is pressed... you would need x2 things before making comments in the main part of the code...

1. At Top of the View Controller (code) where you have `class ViewController: UIViewController` - add `UITextFieldDelegate`. So at the end it should look like:

   `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`
2. in the same View Controller (code) in the func `viewDidLoad` add
   `self.textField.delegate = self`

Then...  as mentioned by 'Abhinandan Pratap', incorporate the below code to control behaviour of the KeyBoard when pressing 'Return':

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

However, if you want to minimize the Keyboard by Tapping elsewhere on the screen, the following on its own will suffice by using 'TouchesBegan' (provided you're not using scroll view)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

If your using scrollView for the screen, you need to use `self.view.endEditing(true)` in conjunction with `UITapGesture` to making tapping outside close down the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! and thank you so much for explaining it so detailed, it worked wonders! :D I didn't know who to give the correct answer to, but since it was "Abhinandan Pratap" that wrote the code first i gave it to him, but thank you man! :)

Comment: Declaration of touchesBegan has changed, so it should be like this:                `func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes will be helpful use both ways (Swift 4):

First use declare a delegate `UITextFieldDelegate` where you have `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

Second you have to set `self.textField.delegate = self` in initialization
part (as usual in `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` or `viewDidLoad`).

And then fill method as:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    //or use on superView of textField
    //superView.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do work

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: and where should i paste this? :)

Comment: use it instead of resignFirstResponder when you need to hide keyboard

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Confirm the `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
 {
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
 }
```