# Exit Keyboard in UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, textfield

I inserted a text field into my application and now there is no way for the keyboard to close. How would I get the keyboard to close? Maybe by a button or clicking outside the textfield or something? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761648/close-the-keyboard-on-uitextfield

Maybe you want to check this out ;)

Comment: Perhaps this might answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306240/iphone-dismiss-keyboard-when-touching-outside-of-textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your button to an action and then add this line

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a textfield named myTextField, set the Delegate of the UITextField to your ViewController, add a referencing outlet between the File's Owner and the UITextField, then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == myTextField) {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in your .h file and define
`-- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` delegate in your .m file as follows:

```
-- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{

[textField  resignFirstResponder];

return YES;

}
```

Most important do not forget to set delegate property of your UITextFiled Object "self" as:
`m_txtTextFiled.delegate = self;` when u allocate its intance.